# PHP GMAIL Contacts XML Parsing with DOMDocument and cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl, gmail, domdocument

What I am trying to get currently is just the attribute of gd:email that is the "address=" only nothing else as of the moment. Which I can get to the xml portion, heck I can even get any given think per say as long as its within tags like   but to get the attribute of any given one like in my case..  I am completely confused on. I used to know how to do it but its been so long since I did anything that wasn't simple for XML useage. so I done messed my own self up..

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/' xmlns:gContact='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008' xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
        <id>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com</id>
        <updated>2011-06-30T00:07:48.706Z</updated>
        <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
        <title type='text'>Taco Bells's Contacts</title>
        <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='http://www.google.com/'/>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full'/>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full'/>
        <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#batch' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/batch'/>
        <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full?max-results=5'/>
        <link rel='next' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full?start-index=6&max-results=5'/>
        <author>
            <name>Taco Bell</name>
            <email>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com</email>
        </author>
        <generator version='1.0' uri='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds'>Contacts</generator>
        <openSearch:totalResults>90</openSearch:totalResults>
        <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
        <openSearch:itemsPerPage>5</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
        <entry>
            <id>http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/base/0</id>
            <updated>2010-01-27T00:11:57.430Z</updated>
            <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
            <title type='text'>Taco B</title>
            <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo' type='image/*' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/photos/media/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/0/8_XL_JoAPon1k7SNixI2iA'/>
            <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo' type='image/*' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/photos/media/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/0'/>
            <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/0'/>
            <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/0/1264551117430000'/>
            <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com' primary='true'/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <id>http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/base/1</id>
            <updated>2007-08-01T18:02:04.410Z</updated>
            <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
            <title type='text'></title>
            <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo' type='image/*' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/photos/media/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/1/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg'/>
            <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/1'/>
            <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/1/1185991324410001'/>
            <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@sbcglobal.net' primary='true'/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <id>http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/base/2</id>
            <updated>2010-01-27T00:11:57.430Z</updated>
            <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
            <title type='text'>Steve Sattler</title>
            <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo' type='image/*' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/photos/media/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/2/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg'/>
            <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/2'/>
            <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/2/1264551117430000'/>
            <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com' primary='true'/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <id>http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/base/3</id>
            <updated>2010-01-27T00:11:57.430Z</updated>
            <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
            <title type='text'>Michael Montana</title>
            <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo' type='image/*' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/photos/media/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/3/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg'/>
            <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/3'/>
            <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/3/1264551117430000'/>
            <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@comcast.net' primary='true'/>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <id>http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/base/4</id>
            <updated>2007-08-01T18:02:04.410Z</updated>
            <category scheme='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#kind' term='http://schemas.google.com/contact/2008#contact'/>
            <title type='text'></title>
            <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#edit-photo' type='image/*' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/photos/media/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/4/1B2M2Y8AsgTpgAmY7PhCfg'/>
            <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/4'/>
            <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='http://www.google.com/mate/feeds/contacts/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40gmail.com/full/4/1185991324410001'/>
            <gd:email rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#other' address='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@courant.com' primary='true'/>
        </entry>
    </feed>
```

with code that looks like (this is the whole script (currently))

```
$user = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";

// ref: http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps.html

// step 1: login
$login_url = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin";
$fields = array(
    'Email' => $user,
    'Passwd' => $password,
    'service' => 'cp', // <== contact list service code
    'source' => 'test-google-contact-grabber',
    'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,$login_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$result = curl_exec($curl);

$returns = array();

foreach (explode("\n",$result) as $line)
{
    $line = trim($line);
    if (!$line) continue;
    list($k,$v) = explode("=",$line,2);

    $returns[$k] = $v;
}

curl_close($curl);

// step 2: grab the contact list
$feed_url = "http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/$user/full?&max-results=5";

$header = array(
    'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $returns['Auth'],
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $feed_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($result);
$arrFeeds = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('entry') as $node) {
    $monkey = $node->getAttribute('{gd:email}');
    $itemRSS = array($monkey->nodeValue);
array_push($arrFeeds, $itemRSS);
}
array_unique($arrFeeds);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at [`DOMDocument`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://ca.php.net/domxpath). In order to get nodes that are part of a particular namespace, like the `email` node which is part of the `gd` namespace, you need to register the namespace with the `DOMXPath` object using [`DOMXPath::registerNamespace()`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.registernamespace.php). The namespace URI can usually be found at the top of the XML document.

**Example:**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadXML($result);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');

$emails = $xpath->query('//gd:email');

foreach ( $emails as $email )
{
  echo $email->getAttribute('address');

  // To get the title.
  // This could also be done using XPath.
  // You can also use ->nodeValue instead of ->textContent.
  echo $email->parentNode->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
}
```

In the example above, `$result` is the result of `$result = curl_exec($ch);`.

Comment: That is awesome! I don't think I would have come to that conclusion on my own for a good while at the least. Curious however. "//gd:email" what does the "//" portion mean? Like what is the significance of that? Then "$xpath->registerNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');" is there anyway to not have the http://...... part cause im thinking what if theres ever something different..

Comment: @chris - The // just means: "Selects nodes in the document from the current node that match the selection no matter where they are". For more information see [XPath Syntax at W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp). The namespace URI always starts with the scheme (i.e. http) so you have to keep in there.

Comment: Just before you answered this. I realized I also want to get the "title" of every "entry" so I can put the name of the person with the email. I failed to realize and mention that in my originally post. Is there a means I can incorporate that into this that you've shown above or does the idea have to be rewritten into a different context to manage that?

Comment: @chris - I've added a few lines to my answer. See if that works for you.

Comment: That line does work. However I just happened to realize upon refreshing my content that the loop is now running 50 times. As in it completes its cycle, then re-runs the loop again and again. I dumped the raw xml output to a textarea just to be sure the XML wasn't some how coming out that large, and its not. Right now I have the XML maxed at 50 entries it can be more or less. But my output from the loop is 2500 entries any idea why that would happen? Ive never had that happen with any loops ive done in the past unless it was a while loop and I set my numbers wrong :-)

Comment: HAH, nevermind... I am just beyond tired and likely shouldn't be coding currently. I forgot to remove a section of code I added while I was working on trying to solve it myself before anyone came back with an answer. And upon realizing that and removing that, presto it works proper! Thanks for all your help, and thanks for the link to that Xpath thing I think thats going to give me great insight on this and future projects I run into.

Comment: @chris - I tried the code I wrote above using your sample XML and it's working great. Only went through it once. Is this inside a function? If so, does it get called multiple times somewhere else? Is it inside a foreach/while/do/for loop? There must be something calling that part of the code multiple times.

Comment: @FrancoisDeschenes How can i tell difference between work and mobile phone? It does not have a special attribute for it.

`<gd:phoneNumber rel="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#mobile">+372555555</gd:phoneNumber>`

Comment: Main point (why it helped me) understanding that we should register xml namespace (of google) to get google fields. BTW you can add `?alt=json` to your rrequest url to retriev data as json string...

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts//full?max-results='.$max_results.'&oauth_token='.$accesstoken.'&alt=json&updated-min=2007-03-16T00:00:00';
function curl_file_get_contents($url)
{

$curl = curl_init();
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';
//The URL to fetch. This can also be    set    when initializing a session with curl_init().
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);    
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('GData-Version: 2.0'));
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE); //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);    //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.    
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPGET,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);  //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);    //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);    //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
//curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.

$contents = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
return $contents;
}
```