# How to get full contact information from Google using PHP?

Tags: php, api, oauth

I am using Oauth 2.0 to Import Contacts but I am getting only the email addresses. Any Way to Get Other Fields? Also, How can I create Contacts using Google API.
Need to use Only PHP.

Here is my Code:

```
//setting parameters
$authcode= $_GET["code"];
$clientid='xxxxxxx';
$clientsecret='secret';
$redirecturi='validate.php';
$fields=array(
 'code'=>  urlencode($authcode),
 'client_id'=>  urlencode($clientid),
 'client_secret'=>  urlencode($clientsecret),
 'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($redirecturi),
 'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
);
//url-ify the data for the POST
$fields_string='';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$fields_string=rtrim($fields_string,'&');
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,5);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//to trust any ssl certificates
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);
//close connection
curl_close($ch);
//extracting access_token from response string
$response=  json_decode($result);
$accesstoken= $response->access_token;
//passing accesstoken to obtain contact details
$xmlresponse=  file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default     /full?oauth_token='.$accesstoken.'&max-results=5');
//reading xml using SimpleXML
 $xml=  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
 $result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');
 foreach ($result as $title) {
  $addrss=$title->attributes()->address;
  echo $addrss."<br><br>";
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you're only parsing the XML for `gd:email` then you certainly only get the email address. See the [Contact kind documentation](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?hl=de#gdContactKind) for an overview of the elements you could also parse for.

For creating contacts you can just issue a POST request with the contact details in the body to the same endpoint:

```
https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full
```

For detailed documentation on the format of the contact details, see the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#creating_contacts).

Answer (score 0):

[PHP GMAIL Contacts XML Parsing with DOMDocument and cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530050/php-gmail-contacts-xml-parsing-with-domdocument-and-curl)

Dnt know about adding contacts but the above link should get you started in the right direction, create a DomDocument Class and append Nodes to it (php manual). I think would be the way to go, keeping inline with Google contact API's

Comment: use [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/index) v3.0 of google contact api, not gdata which is v2. Also use [link](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to get access to contact API (or other api) save the xml locally to ur disk and work with XML, as the data returned can be overwhelming