# Google Contacts Import to Mysql in PHP via OAuth

Tags: php, api, contacts

i was creating a small app using jquery mobile with server side language as php,so i want to import all my google contacts (Names,Numbers & Email) into a mysql database using the OAuth. Currently im using the following script which can grab only email addresses but is there a way for the same to import names & numbers as well?

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
        <title>Email address list - Import Gmail or Google contacts</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        a:link {color:Chocolate;text-decoration: none;}
        a:hover {color:CornflowerBlue;}
        .logo{width:100%;height:110px;border:2px solid black;background-color:#666666;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="logo" >
            <a href="http://25labs.com/" >
                <img style="padding-top: 10px;" src="http://25labs.com/wp-content/themes/TheStyle/images/logo.png"></img>
            </a>
        </div>
<br/>
        <div><b>Visit Tutorial: </b><a style="font-size:17px;" href="http://25labs.com/import-gmail-or-google-contacts-using-google-contacts-data-api-3-0-and-oauth-2-0-in-php/" >Import Gmail or Google contacts using Google Contacts Data API 3.0 and OAuth 2.0 in PHP</a></div>
            <br/>
        <div style="padding-left: 50px;">
<?php
$client_id = '';
$client_secret = '';
$redirect_uri = '';
$max_results = 1000;

$auth_code = $_GET["code"];

function curl_file_get_contents($url)
{
 $curl = curl_init();
 $userAgent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,$url);   //The URL to fetch. This can also be set when initializing a session with curl_init().
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);    //TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);   //The number of seconds to wait while trying to connect.    

 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent); //The contents of the "User-Agent: " header to be used in a HTTP request.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  //To follow any "Location: " header that the server sends as part of the HTTP header.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE); //To automatically set the Referer: field in requests where it follows a Location: redirect.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);   //The maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); //To stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate.
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

 $contents = curl_exec($curl);
 curl_close($curl);
 return $contents;
}

$fields=array(
    'code'=>  urlencode($auth_code),
    'client_id'=>  urlencode($client_id),
    'client_secret'=>  urlencode($client_secret),
    'redirect_uri'=>  urlencode($redirect_uri),
    'grant_type'=>  urlencode('authorization_code')
);
$post = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
$post = rtrim($post,'&');

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,5);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$response =  json_decode($result);
$accesstoken = $response->access_token;

$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results='.$max_results.'&oauth_token='.$accesstoken;
$xmlresponse =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
if((strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Authorization required'))>0) && (strlen(stristr($xmlresponse,'Error '))>0))
{
    echo "<h2>OOPS !! Something went wrong. Please try reloading the page.</h2>";
    exit();
}
echo "<h3>Email Addresses:</h3>";
$xml =  new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
$result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');

foreach ($result as $title) {
  echo $title->attributes()->address . "<br>";
}
?>
</div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: See this question for the details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11920525/how-to-get-full-contact-information-from-google-using-php

Comment: Check https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/2.0/elements?hl=de#gdContactKind

Answer (score 0):

This code uses ZF2 client but you can get the idea:

```
        $client = new \Zend\Http\Client('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=100000&alt=json', array(
            'adapter' => 'Zend\Http\Client\Adapter\Curl'
        ));
        $client->setHeaders(array(
            array('Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $ACCESS_TOKEN)
        ));

        $client->send();
        if ($client->getResponse()->getStatusCode() != 200) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $output = json_decode($client->getResponse()->getBody());
            if ($output) {
                $entries = $output->feed->entry;

                foreach ($entries as $e) {
                    print_r($e); // here you can see all the available information
                }
            }
        }
```